# Check if BST node has a sibling

Tags: python, recursion, binary-search-tree, siblings, treenode

I am trying to check if a node has a sibling using a recursive method, but it seems that my method doesn't go into the tree besides the first two children. So in this example, if I want to check if 6 has a sibling, my recursive call doesn't reach it.
[image]

```
def sibling(T,k):
    x = T.find(k)
    if x == None:
        return None
    if x == T.right:
        if not T.left.is_empty:
            return T.left.key
        else:
            return None
    elif x == T.left:
        if not T.right.is_empty:
            return T.right.key
        else:
            return None
    elif k > T.key:
        sibling(T.right, k)
    elif k < T.key:
        sibling(T.left, k)
    pass
```

Here is the expected output:

```
T = bst_list[3]
sibling(T,0): 3
sibling(T,1): None
sibling(T,2): None
sibling(T,3): 0
sibling(T,4): None
sibling(T,5): None
sibling(T,6): 8
sibling(T,7): 10
sibling(T,8): 6
sibling(T,9): 13
```

Here is my output:

```
T = bst_list[3]
sibling(T,0): 3
sibling(T,1): None
sibling(T,2): None
sibling(T,3): 0
sibling(T,4): None
sibling(T,5): None
sibling(T,6): None
sibling(T,7): None
sibling(T,8): None
sibling(T,9): None
```

Also this is my BST class which I cannot edit:

```
def __init__(self, k=None):
        if (k is None): # if k is None, it will create an empty tree
            self.is_empty = True
        else:           # otherwise it will create a tree with a single node, containing k
            self.is_empty = False
            self.key=k
            self.left=BST()   # left  child will be an empty tree
            self.right=BST()  # right child will be an empty tree

 def find(self,key,parent=None,return_parent=False):
        # Returns address of node where key is.
        # If return_parent is True, it also returns the parent of the node where key is
        # Returning the parent makes deletions simpler
        if self.is_empty:
            if return_parent:
                return None, None
            return None
        if self.key == key:
            if return_parent:
                return parent, self
            return self
        if self.key>key:
            return self.left.find(key,self,return_parent)
        return self.right.find(key,self,return_parent)
```

Comment: You don't do anything with return values of recursive calls.

Comment: Good to remember: the _only_ function call that can actually return a value to your `find()`  function is the _initial_ call.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! I just had to add return to the recursive calls >.< !!!!

```
elif k > T.key:
        return sibling(T.right, k)
    elif k < T.key:
        return sibling(T.left, k)
```